# Configure Visual Studio Project for Universal Windows Platform

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake, win-universal-app

I've been trying to identify the correct variables to set to create a UWP project using VS2015, and the projects generated are missing a few critical tags.

I'm using CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=WindowsStore and CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.0. This correctly identifies and sets the target platform tag, but does not set the following 'Globals' Properties in the PropertyGroup of the .vcxproj file

```
<AppContainerApplication>true</AppContainerApplication>
<ApplicationType>Windows Store</ApplicationType>
<WindowsTargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10240.0</WindowsTargetPlatformMinVersion>
<ApplicationTypeRevision>10.0</ApplicationTypeRevision>
```

Has anyone successfully created a UWP project using CMake?

Regards,
Mario

Comment: What version of cmake are you using? Make sure it's above 3.4. I'm using 3.6.1, following the command you provide, it successfully generates the "Globals" properties you listed.

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried out Microsoft cmake? https://github.com/Microsoft/CMake

Comment: I'm using 3.6.1 too. No I have never tried out Microsoft cmake before.

Comment: Could you paste your CMakeList.txt file, I'll try locally.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't paste our CMakeList.txt, because it includes company-specific implementation. Do you have an idea, why it fails to create all properties?

Comment: Nope. Just tried Microsoft cmake https://github.com/Microsoft/CMake, also works. I'm building opencv project files using Microsoft cmake, all the "global" properties you mentioned are correctly generated.

Comment: Try if you can get the same result, create an blank folder with a blank file CMakeList.txt, cd to the folder and run "CMake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=WindowsStore -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.0", check if the generated project file contains the macros you mentioned.

Comment: I noticed that you're targeting 10.0.10240. In my environment, I'm using 14393. I have VS2015 Update 3 and 14393 SDK installed. Maybe that's the difference.